# Eclipse PHP Developer Tools crash after opening a PHP file

Tags: java, php, eclipse, exception, 64-bit

i've a problem with eclipse on windows. Eclipse is crashing after opening a file. See details:

im using eclipse PDT (PHP Developer Tools) helios 64-Bit BuildId 20100617-1415.
Im using a Windows 7 64-Bit 4GB RAM 3,00 GHZ DualCore. Here my Javaversion:

```
JAVA_VERSION="1.7.0"
OS_NAME="Windows"
OS_VERSION="5.2"
OS_ARCH="amd64"
SOURCE=" .:6c778574d873 corba:e2f0036f712a deploy:ff2d46573ceb hotspot:6c6a2299029a hotspot/make/closed:80b9d510a421 hotspot/src/closed:634748630fb2 hotspot/test/closed:c481bad2398f install:0c651f8a91c5 jaxp:114654a331e2 jaxws:81a1b110f70c jdk:d19a89fdfb9b jdk/make/closed:b5692ae0a608 jdk/src/closed:191255f238f8 jdk/test/closed:436a6034af75 langtools:4d0807934c30 pubs:d1669b0287b0 sponsors:b93d7ce5ce71"
BUILD_TYPE=commercial
```

I used the Windows Offline (64-Bit) Download-Link from this Java Site:
http://www.java.com/de/download/manual.jsp.

I've created a new Project in Windows, then i copied the code in Windows-Explorer in the workspace/project-folder and execute the refresh-command over the whole project.

When i'm trying to open a file in the project, eclipse says no response. So that i only can kill the process. The last time i get a errormessage:

```
!SESSION 2014-04-02 12:39:23.739 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20100608-0911
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.php.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.php.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2014-04-02 12:52:55.074
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Validating Stadtbäckerei am Gänsemarkt - Hamburg".
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:481)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass_LockClassName(ClasspathManager.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:481)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass_LockClassName(ClasspathManager.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-04-02 12:53:35.607
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
!SESSION 2014-04-02 12:55:16.688 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20100608-0911
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.php.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.php.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2014-04-02 12:55:22.296
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.
!SESSION Wed Apr 02 13:52:19 CEST 2014 -----------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2014-04-02 13:52:19.445
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

Can someone help me? I want to work with eclipse, but it seems that i've to use an other IDE for Webdeveloping.

Answer (score 0):

Your JVM has exhausted the limit on Permanent Generation (PermGen) memory (which is not the general heap).  Please see http://wiki.eclipse.org/IRC_FAQ#I.27m_having_memory.2C_heap.2C_or_permgen_problems.2C_what_can_I_do.3F , https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_permgen_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F , and http://eclipsenuggets.blogspot.com/2007/10/does-your-eclipse-3.html .